# Page created by MFMailComposeViewController could not be shown because of hierarchy - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, hierarchy, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I attempt to add a function, that is a mail page would pop up after the user touched a row in a table. Namely, it means that the user could activate a "function" (here the name of that function is "orderOfSendAnEmailToReportTheProblem") when the row is tapped. All of my codes were shown below. (This kind of code has been proposed by several genii on Stackoverflow...)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ReportProblem : UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

func orderOfSendAnEmailToReportTheProblem() {
    let mailComposeViewController = configureMailController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        showMailError()
    }
}
//Activate the series of the commands of sending the email.


func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposeVC.setToRecipients(["my email"])
    mailComposeVC.setSubject("Yo")

    return mailComposeVC
}
//Set the recipient and the title of this email automatically.

func showMailError() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not sned the email.", message: "Oops, something was wrong, please check your internet connection once again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
    self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil) //If you conform the protocol of NSObject instead of UIViewController, you could not finish this line successfully.
}
//Set a alert window so that it would remind the user when the device could not send the email successfully.

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//Set this final step so that the device would go to the previous window when you finish sending the email.
}
```

However, a problem occurred. When I test it on my real device, and after I tapped that particular row, nothing happened, no any new page pop up... The Xcode only showed that "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" I have tried several ways, such as "view.bringSubview(toFront: mailComposeVC)" or adding the codes shown below at the end of my codes, but nothing worked.

```
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topController
}
```

I noticed that some other people also would face similar problems when they want to create the alert window, and the solution of that is to create an independent UIWindow, but I want to use mailComposeController to present the email page instead. Some others also faced some problems about MFMailComposeViewController, but their problems are not concerning to hierarchy. I was a novice of swift, and I was haunted by this problem for a whole day... I used swift 4 to develop my App, is anyone know how to solve this problem here?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I'm writing another way to present which I'm using for generic views.
Have Some code in another class for presentation of view so that you can reuse them throughout the app with these two methods.

```
func slideInFromRight(parentView:UIView,childView:UIView) {
    childView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: parentView.frame.maxX, y: 0)
    parentView.addSubview(childView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        childView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    })
}

func slideOutToRight(view:UIView) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: view.frame.maxX, y: 0)
    },completion:{(completed:Bool) in
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

Now use these methods to present and remove custom view controller as follows

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let vc = YourViewController().instantiate()
self.addChildViewController(vc)
let view = vc.view

view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: window!.frame.width, height: window!.frame.height-20)
//Here Animation is my custom presenter class and shared is it's shared instance.

Animation.shared.slideInFromRight(parentView: window!, childView: view)

//Or you can use current View controller's view 
Animation.shared.slideInFromRight(parentView: self.view!, childView: view)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that your codes did not work, either. Fortunately, when I fixed your codes to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = mailComposeVC`, it worked, and the email page finally pop up.

Nonetheless, there’s no any animation between the transition of pages. Moreover, after I chose not to save the email and left the email page, I could not choose any other button. It seems that my App could not work when the rootController was changed. Furthermore, I still did not know how to recover the rootController to the original one. Do you know any another solution?…

Comment: Updated my answer...try this if it works for.....if you still get any problems let me know.....maybe I could help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Genius Vivek Singh, your way looks good, but it's a little bit tedious. Moreover, it still did not work in my project... (It seems that you used some codes about UIView, such as `parentView`, `childView`, and `view`. However, I used `MFMailComposeViewController` which seems is a little bit different from original view...I am not sure whether this theory is correct or not...)

However, I have found the solution. I presume that the problem is that after the user clicked the row in another tableViewController (here is `SettingTVController`), it would activate the function "`orderOfSendAnEmailToReportTheProblem( )`" which is in "another " viewController (here is `ReportProblem`). Because there are two different viewController, some kind of conflict occurred.

Therefore, I move my whole codes I posted in the above question to my original tableViewController, so that the user would not go into another viewController when they activate the function, and there's no hierarchy problem anymore.

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
import MessageUI

class SettingTVController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

var settingTitleConnection = showData()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //skip
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   //skip
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   //skip
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //skip
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   //skip
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row == 2 && tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.section == 1 {
        orderOfSendAnEmailToReportTheProblem()
    } else {
      //skip
    }

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

//-----<The codes below is used to construct the function of reporting problem with email>-----
func orderOfSendAnEmailToReportTheProblem() {
    let mailComposeViewController = configureMailController()
    self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        showMailError()
    }
}
//Activate the series of the commands of sending the email.

func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposeVC.setToRecipients(["datototest@icloud.com"])
    mailComposeVC.setSubject("Reporting of Problems of Rolling")

    return mailComposeVC
}
//Set the recipient and the title of this email automatically.

func showMailError() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not send the email.", message: "Oops, something was wrong, please check your internet connection once again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
    self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil) //If you conform the protocol of NSObject instead of UIViewController, you could not finish this line successfully.
}
//Set a alert window so that it would remind the user when the device could not send the email successfully.

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    //UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//Set this final step so that the device would go to the previous window when you finish sending the email.
//-----<The codes above is used to construct the function of reporting problem with email>-----
}
```

I posted my codes above so that it may help others who face similar problem someday. Once again, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are facing a view hierarchy issue. But I am able to achieve the mail share option in swift 4. I followed exactly same steps.

1. Check if mail can be sent:

   MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
2. Configure mail body:

   ```
   private func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
   let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
   mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
   mailComposeViewController.setMessageBody("MESSAGE BODY", isHTML: true)
   return mailComposeViewController
   ```

   }
3. Present mail VC:

   `present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true)`
4. confirm optional protocol and dismiss the view explicitly:

   ```
   func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
   controller.dismiss(animated: true)
   ```

   }